# Label is not floating when value set through DA Oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex-20.1

I'm facing issue for a text-field of template optional-floating. I'm setting values on it through DA. But It label still not moving upword. Please see below screenshot.
[image]

However if I click on these fields and again click outside it will work normally.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Share your code DA to see, but I think you are not setting the value well

Answer (score 0):

Use the setter function:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.1/aexjs/global.html#$s

```
$s("P1_ITEM", "10", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this still existing problem, on a dynamic action of change event to the page items, execute a Javascript code:

```
    $('#P1_PAGE_ITEM').addClass('js-show-label');
```

Note: Make sure "fire on initialization" setting is turned on